# Android DataBinding build error

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

I have a problem with Data Binding library for Android.
I have a freshly installed Android Studio v2.0 and newly created project.
The problem is that when I try to add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

to my build.gradle, I get this error while trying to build the project:
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.

> Could not initialize class android.databinding.parser.XMLLexer

The build.gradle files look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.silgrid.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: take a look on the prerequisite of the post http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2016/07/android-data-binding-part-1.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me it got fixed after updating to Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Updating gradle version in main gradle file has solved this problem for me.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}
```